# Infinite series. Is it a Riemann sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

I encountered the infinite series in a probability exercise. I want to analyze the asymptotic behavior of 
\begin{align*}
S = \sum_{k \geq n} \frac{1}{2^k} \cdot \frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{k+1}.
\end{align*}
In fact, in the problem, it is 
\begin{align*}
T = \sum_{k \geq k_n} \frac{1}{2^k} \cdot \frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{k+1},
\end{align*}
where $b_n + 1 < 2^{k_n} \leq 2 (b_n + 1)$ and $b_n = \frac{n}{\log_2 n}$. It is easy to show that $T$ is convergent, but what I need is its order or asymptotic behavior. My guess is $T \approx 1 / k_n$ or $T \approx 1/ \log_2 b_n$ because this is what I want to continue my proof. I also used wolframalpha.com to calculate $S$. Here is what it does:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{2^k} \cdot \frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{k+1} = 1 - \ln 2.
\end{align*}
It gave me a closed form. How can I prove or disprove my guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A sketch of an idea:** consider $f$ defined on $(-1,1)$ by
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k(k-1)}
$$
Observe that "by properties of power series" $f$ is nicely smooth, and further that you can differentiate termwise:
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{x^{k-1}}{k-1}
$$
$$
f''(x) = \sum_{k=n}^\infty x^{k-2} = \sum_{k=n-2}^\infty x^{k}
$$
so that you can compute $f''$ in a closed-form, and then integrate that closed-form twice to get $f$. Then, you want $f(1/2)$.

Comment: This is a great idea! I have a follow-up question. Another infinite sum I want to analyze is $\sum 2^k / (k \cdot (k+1))$. It goes to infinity. How should I work on this?

Comment: Do you want tight asymptotics, or up to constants (Theta style)? I'd personally suggest a comparison series/integral if the former, or cheaper ways to get a loose bound if the latter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I should have stated clearly that the sum is from $1$ to $n$. And I have found a way (relatively) tight bound by using comparison series/integral, just as you suggested. Thank you again!!!

Comment: You're welcome!